# Alternative to ethtool on MontaVista embedded Linux

Tags: networking, embedded, networkcard

I am running MontaVista Linux Professional Edition 3.1 on an embedded system. My version of this distribution doesn't seem to have `ethtool` available, and using `mii-tool` gives the following error:

```
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth0' failed: Operation not supported
```

Is there another alternative way to access the configuration options that `ethtool` provides?

Comment: I should have added, I am most interested in the offload parameters, i.e. the ethtool -k flag.

Answer (score 2):

With a recent enough kernel, you could have a look at

```
/sys/class/net/eth0/speed
/sys/class/net/eth0/duplex
```

Sometimes the `dmesg` output will show the information when the speed is negotiated. You may have to turn some verbose mode on in the NIC driver (see `modinfo` output on the module for what parameters (to be set in modprobe.conf or modules.conf) are supported).

If you're looking for other parameters like the offload parameters, the kernel API to retrieve them is called "ethtool" (`SIOCETHTOOL` ioctl), so I doubt there's any other utility to get it.

You should be able to compile ethtool easily though, there's no special dependency required.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't appear to have those files, and dmesg doesn't give up any info I'm interested. I've added a comment to my original question clarifying exactly what I'm looking for.